# Error in python-selenium bindings for chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to create an instance of chrome driver after installing chrome driver successfully by seeing the post [here](http://install-climber.blogspot.in/2012/06/setupseleniumchromedriverubuntulinux.html). 
As shown in the post i downloaded `chrome-driver 64-bit` for python. And i moved the chromedriver executable file to `/usr/bin`, and tried the following code

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Chromedriver()
```

**Result**     :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/local/user/<ipython console> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Chromedriver'
```

Also when tried the following

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

**Result:**

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/local/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout)
     49         RemoteWebDriver.__init__(self,
     50             command_executor=ExtensionConnection("127.0.0.1", self.profile,
---> 51             self.binary, timeout),
     52             desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
     53 

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.pyc in __init__(self, host, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout)
     45         self.profile.add_extension()
     46 
---> 47         self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
     48         _URL = "http://%s:%d/hub" % (HOST, PORT)
     49         RemoteConnection.__init__(

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.pyc in launch_browser(self, profile)
     42 
     43         self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
---> 44         self._wait_until_connectable()
     45 
     46     def kill(self):

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.pyc in _wait_until_connectable(self)
     79                 raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
     80                       "before we could connect. The output was: %s" %
---> 81                       self._get_firefox_output())
     82             if count == 30:
     83                 self.kill()

WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: *** LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Opening database\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\nFailed to dlopen /usr/lib/libX11.so.6\ndlerror says: /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32\n'
```

I am unable know whats happening here, and why both chrome and firefox web drivers are not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its `webdriver.Chrome()` **not** `webdriver.Chromedriver()`

and you can avoid copying the executable in /usr/bin ..etc by specifying the path to the executable as an argument

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='...')
```

that way you can avoid one extra step and also have the driver checked into your source control directory etc.