# How to launch Selenium webbrowser with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2o0Z.png)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Selenium program\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe")
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can any one help me with this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is very incomplete.

To run Selenium with Chrome you need to install [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). You can either download it and install, or use [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node) (`npm install chromedriver --global`).

If you're sure you have it installed, alongside with Python, and everything is working, then here's a basic example (from `ChromeDriver` page).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

The error your getting (`AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome' Process finished with exit code 1`) seems to be because you don't have ChromeDriver installed.

In your code (the image you linked to the question) you're using `webbrowser.open(url, new=2)`. Try to open using `driver.get(url)` to see if it works.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220588/error-in-python-selenium-bindings-for-chromedriver) another similar question, if you want to check.